# ezplot not working unless global variable is written

Tags: matlab, plot

I'm trying to plot the following function

```
% k-nn density estimation
% localSearcher is a handle class responsible for finding the k closest points to x
function z = k_nearest_neighbor(x, localSearcher)            

    % Total point count
    n = localSearcher.getPointCount();

    % Get the indexes of the k closest points to x
    % (the k parameter is contained inside the localSearcher class)
    idx = localSearcher.search(x);

    % k is constant
    k = length(idx);  

    % Compute the volume (i.e. the hypersphere centered in x that encloses every
    % sample in idx)
    V = localSearcher.computeVolume(x, idx);

    % The estimate for the density function is p(x) = k / (n * V)        
    z = k / (n * V); 

end
```

I know for sure that the above algorithm is correct, because I get a reasonable plot using the following function

```
% Plot the values of k_nearest_neighbor(x, searcher) by sampling it manually
function manualPlot(samples, searcher)

    a = -2;
    b = 2;
    n = 1000;
    h = (b - a) / n;
    sp = linspace(a, b, n);
    pt = zeros(n);
    areas = zeros(n);
    estimated_pdf = @(x)k_nearest_neighbor(x, searcher);  
    area = 0;
    for i = 1 : length(sp)
        x = sp(i);        
        pt(i) = estimated_pdf(x);

        area = area + h * pt(i);
        areas(i) = area;
    end

    figure, hold on  
    title('k-nn density estimation');
    plot(sp, pt, sp, areas, ':r');
    legend({'$p_n(x)$', '$\int_{-2}^{x} p_n(x)\, \, dx$'}, 'Interpreter', 'latex', 'FontSize', 14);
    plot(samples,zeros(length(samples)),'ro','markerfacecolor', [1, 0, 0]);    

    axis auto
end
```

called by

```
 function test2()

    clear all
    close all

    % Pattern Classification (page 175)
    samples = [71 / 800; 128 / 800; 223 / 800; 444 / 800; 475 / 800; 546 / 800; 641 / 800; 780 / 800];

    % 3-nn density estimation
    searcher = NaiveNearestSearcher(samples, 3); 
    manualPlot(samples, searcher);    
 end
```

which outputs

[image: Manually sampling the anonymous function works flawlessly]

However, if I try to do the same thing with `ezplot`

```
% Plot the values of k_nearest_neighbor using ezplot
function autoPlot(samples, searcher)

    estimated_pdf = @(x)k_nearest_neighbor(x, searcher);    

    figure, hold on    
    ezplot(estimated_pdf, [-2,2]);
    title('k-nn density estimation');
    legend({'$p_n(x)$', '$\int_{-2}^{x} p_n(x)\, \, dx$'}, 'Interpreter', 'latex', 'FontSize', 14);
    plot(samples,zeros(length(samples)),'ro','markerfacecolor',[1,0,0]);    

    axis auto
end
```

I get the following incorrect result

[image: ezplot doesn't work]

No warnings are issued from the console.
It's like the `searcher` parameter passed to the anonymous function

```
estimated_pdf = @(x)k_nearest_neighbor(x, searcher);    
ezplot(estimated_pdf, [-2,2]);
```

goes "out of scope" (or something) before `ezplot` terminates.
The really weird thing is that adding

```
function z = k_nearest_neighbor(x, localSearcher)

    [... same identical code ... ]

   global becauseWhyNotVector;
   % becauseWhyNotVector(end + 1) = 1;  NOT WORKING, I must use the x variable for some reason
   becauseWhyNotVector(end + 1) = x;

end
```

apparently fixes the problem (!).
Here's the full [source code](https://hostr.co/MZZ5qZvbHKxl), I'm using MATLAB R2011a.

Comment: I think about the output from `k_nearest_neighbor` what type of output is that? The guess is that you do not get the output you expect from the function. Try to use the debugger and set a breakpoint after `k_nearest_neighbor` (I guess that you know how to use the debugger).

Comment: Yes, you're right: the problem is that `ezplot` was calling `k_nearest_neighbor` passing all the sample points at once.
The problem is fixed now. Also, I didn't notice that MATLAB has a debugger, I was messing with `fprintf` to no avail, thanks for pointing me that :P